# IBM Worklight - Build failed after checking-out from SVN and trying to Build

Tags: svn, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Worklight 5.0.5.

I checkout out a Worklight project from SVN, and when trying to "Build ALl and Deploy" I get `Failed copying web resources to native project`. See log from Eclipse below.

Can you please suggest some approaches to solve this bug?

```
Requested to build 'windows8' but there is no optimization folder for it.
[2013-05-31 18:36:14] FWLST1040E: windowsphone build failed: Failed copying web resources to native project (windowsphone)
[2013-05-31 18:36:14] FWLST1040E: iphone build failed: Failed copying web resources to native project (iphone)
[2013-05-31 18:36:15] FWLST1040E: android build failed: Failed copying web resources to native project (android)
[2013-05-31 18:36:16] FWLST1040E: ipad build failed: Failed copying web resources to native project (ipad)
```

Comment: Does this happen consistently with any Worklight project you check-in and check-out from SVN, or a specific Worklight project you have checked-in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you follow the guidelines for [working with source control systems in Worklight v5.0.5](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/r_integrating_with_source_contro.html).

Workaround: delete the native folder of each environment and run a Build All and Deploy.